# Seconds since midnight to time of day

Tags: r, time, lubridate

There is a post that shows how use `lubridate` to go from time to seconds since midnight.  How about going from seconds since midnight to time of day?

So, instead of using 06:52:32 to get 24752.05, how do I use 24752.05 to get 06:52:32?

Comment: Want to link to the post that shows time -> seconds-since-midnight?

Answer (score 9):

Use `as.POSIXct()` on the sum of the midnight timestamp and your offset, possibly adjusting by setting TZ.

In my default time zone:

```
R> as.POSIXct(trunc(Sys.time(), units="days") + 24752.05)
[1] "2013-01-16 06:52:32.04 CST"
R>
```

Note that the answer (just like the preceding question) can be solved just fine in base R, persistent rumors that every time question has to involve lubridate not withstanding.

Comment: Next you will tell me that it's possible to plot without using ggplot . . .  Can as.POSIX.ct also handle Epoch times?

Comment: Yes, of course (to both parts, but particularly the ggplot one).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, `trunc(Sys.time())` does not give the midnight timestamp

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
format(as.POSIXct('1900-1-1') + 24752.05, '%H:%M:%S')
# [1] "6:52:32"
```

Comment: You can remove the `as.difftime()` as seconds is the native representation.

Comment: Also, note how we get different answers. Your use of 1900-01-01 is questionable as you miss all the adjustment seconds.

Comment: @Drik hmmm, and both our results differ from what OP has in his question.

Comment: OP reversed minutes and seconds.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Leap seconds aren't accounted for by our computers.  The clock is slewed instead.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Read the source, particularly R's `src/main/datetime.c` and look for `leapseconds[]` array.

Comment: @Dirk, forgive me if I'm being dense, but why would you want adjustment seconds in this case?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel See the comment at line 527.  Note that in `C`, `time()%60` always agrees with the wallclock "seconds" value.  In `R`, the same is true of `as.numeric(Sys.time()) %% 60`.

Comment: AFAIK R still does it, the POSIX reference notwithstanding. Try `.leap.seconds` in R.

Comment: It's important for time differences, but not for conversions to/from time_t values.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lubridate` just for variety:

```
library(lubridate)

Sys.time() + seconds(24752.05)
```

or from midnight:

```
as.Date(Sys.time()) + seconds(24752.05)
```

Comment: God only kills kittens when they deserve it.

Answer (score 3):

And of course, you can compute the hours, minutes and seconds directly.  This is based on the definition of POSIX time.  Midnight always has a `time_t` value that is divisible by `86400`.

```
x <- 24752.05

paste(sprintf("%02d", floor(x / 3600)),
      sprintf("%02d", floor(x %% 3600 / 60)),
      sprintf("%02d", floor(x %% 60 )),
      sep=":"
)
## [1] "06:52:32"
```

Comment: Note that this is for GMT timestamps only.